# how can i use javascript:window.open with hyperlink onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, escaping

I'm trying to fire some javascript to open a pop up when the user clicks on the text.  I dont' think im escaping my link properly though and i've been beating my head up for awhile.  Heres my code:

```
var $link = '<a href= "onclick= javascript:window.open("../EForm/Info?formId=' + data.record.Form.Id + ');">info</a>';
```

Here is what gets rendered on the page:

```
<a href="onclick= javascript:window.open(" ..="" eform="" info?formid="1);&quot;">info</a>
```

this obviously isn't right....  Can someone see how i need to change my link above to be properly escaped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape single quotes in your `open` method.

```
var $link = '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open(\'../EForm/Info?formId=' + data.record.Form.Id  + '\');">info</a>';
```

**EDIT**

After a second thought, I recommand you also put the same url to `href` and with a `target=_blank`. this way, even if javascript is disabled, user will still get to the page.

Or simply remove `onclick` all together if you are only going to open the url with a new tab/window because `href` and `target=_blank` will be enough.

Comment: thanks for the suggesion.  Here is the rendered ouput:
<a href="#" "onclick="javascript:window.open('../EForm/Info?formId=1');">info</a>  

but the onclick method is still not firing for some reason..

Comment: @cobolstinks, corrected, i had an extra double quote before `onclick`. it should work now.

Comment: got it changed it to this:
var $link = '<a href="javascript:window.open(\'../EForm/Info?formId=' + data.record.Form.Id + '\');">info</a>';

Answer (score 2):

```
  '<a href="#" onclick= "open_window()">info</a>'

    function open_window(){
    window.open("../EForm/Info?formId='" + data.record.Form.Id);

   }
```